# Why is my network latency higher for a server located nearer to me?

Tags: server, google-cloud-functions, performance-testing, latency, low-latency

We use Google Cloud functions to compute and serve us with some response .

We have the same end point hosted in two different regions .

https://asia-east2-projectName.cloudfunctions.net/getData

https://us-central1-projectName.cloudfunctions.net/getData

When  I ran some concurrency tests using Artillery.io , I was surprised to see the request Latency.

Even though , I am geographically closer (Bangalore) to Asia-east2 server of Google (located in HongKong), the latency is roughly two times when compared to that of US-Central1 server.

For 100 requests generated over 30 sec,

**For Asia-East2 ( HongKong) :**

Request latency: ( in ms)

```
min: 295.4

max: 1107

median: 888.2
```

**For US-Central1 ( Iowa, USA) :**

Request latency: (in ms)

```
min: 438.9

max: 861

median: 478.3
```

Median request latency for a US-based server is 478ms while for asia_east2 , it is 888 ms ( roughly 2 times) even though I am geographically closer to Asia-East2 server than to US-Central1

My Questions are :

1) Isn't latency a direct function of proximity ?

2) If my users are distributed all over the world ,what would be the best way to ensure that latency is as low as possible ?

Comment: Could you run a `traceroute`? Perhaps there's a node increasing your latency (by applying DPI for example).